# Select2 Multi Dropdownlist not loading all selected values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

Good morning,

I have a DropdownListFor with multiple selections.  When I submit the form, it posts fine with all of the selected values, but if there are any model errors when the screen reloads only the first option is selected.  I've set breakpoints in the code, I've verified all values are posted and when I look at the selectlist it shows selected=true for every selected value, however only the first value in the list is selected.

HTML:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CourseTopicsApproved, Model.CourseTopics, "Please select an item", new { @class = "course-topics form-control", multiple = "multiple" })
```

Select2 v4.0.13

```
$(".course-topics").select2({
    placeholder: 'Select Topic(s)',
    allowClear: true,
    multiple: true
});
```

Controller:

```
vm.CourseTopics = SetCourseTopics(vm.CourseTopicTypeId, vm.CourseTopicsApproved);

private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SetCourseTopics(int courseTopicTypeId, IEnumerable<int> selectedValues)
{
    List<SelectListItem> courseTopics = new List<SelectListItem>();

    IEnumerable<CourseTopic> dbCourseTopics = _courseTopicService.GetAll(courseTopicTypeId);

    List<SelectListGroup> groups = new List<SelectListGroup>();

    foreach (var topic in dbCourseTopics.Where(x => x.IsHeaderOnly))
        groups.Add(new SelectListGroup() { Name = topic.Topic });


    foreach (var topic in dbCourseTopics.Where(x => !x.IsHeaderOnly))
        courseTopics.Add(new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = topic.Topic,
            Value = topic.CourseTopicId.ToString(),
            Group = groups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == topic.SubCategory.Topic),
            Selected = (selectedValues != null ? selectedValues.Contains(topic.CourseTopicId) : false)
        });

    return courseTopics;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better solution than this, but this is what I came up with and it seems to be working:

Updated Javascript (Placed this right below the code snippet in my question):

```
var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CourseTopicsApproved))';
var data = JSON.parse(model);

if (data != null) {
    $('.course-topics').select2().val(data).trigger('change');
}
```

If anyone has a better solution please let me know!